# Wix4: Perform validations in Bundle.wxs

Tags: custom-action, wix4

I am using bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication for user inputs with customized theme.xml. I need to perform input validation for the user inputs entered in Options screen. After lot of research I'm not able to find any solution. Basically, Can we perform Custom actions in Bundle.wxs similar to msi? If so how? Thanks.

I tried if BAFunctions.dll can be used but there isn't any useful documentation on how to use them. Alternate solution is to use an msi package to perform as a pre-check steps to perform custom actions. I am looking for better solution. Thanks